# Should i have for each Domain a separate database in DDD?EF MVC codefirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, code-first

I am so new in DDD.
I have a project with 6 Domains. 
[image]

In each domain i have my inf and app layer.My question is about my database.I use entity framework code first (MVC ASP).
Should i create for each domain a separate database ?

Comment: so, you have a bounded context for each domain, right?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU yes

Comment: Curious as to why you have Eric Evans as your profile photo?

Comment: @NaeemSarfraz because he changed my vision about programming and problem solution .i am right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You managed to split the application into multiple bounded contexts (`BCs`), one for each domain (sub-domain). This is the perfect situation.

In this case you should have separate databases (or at least separate tables/collections) for each bounded context. In order to shared data from one `BC` to other `BC` you should use the [Context mapping](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping) strategic DDD pattern to see what is the best technique (depending on your architecture you could use an Anti-corruption layer to share the data between an upstream and a downstream `BC`).

Read more [here](http://culttt.com/2014/11/26/strategies-integrating-bounded-contexts/) about integration types between `BCs`.

PS. In the book [Domain-Driven Design Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134434420) by Vaughn Vernon you can find some integration examples.